# Visual Studio Code: problemMatcher output remains there after the issue is fixed

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a npm task in which I watch my TypeScript application for changes, compile it and then run tests automatically. I'm trying to have Visual Studio Code warn me in the Problems tab whenever a test fails.

While I've managed to achieve that, whenever I fix the code so that the tests pass again, the warning remains in the Problems tab. This is quite bothering, since I would be getting lots of false positives and I might overlook actual test failures. I wonder if there is a way to flush the contents of the Problems tab every time my tests are executed?

Here's my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "start",
            "args": ["start"],
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": [
                    // Omitted for brevity
                ],
                "watching": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": "\\[1\\] Starting 'test'\\.\\.\\.",
                    "endsPattern": ".*Finished 'test' after.*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer my question, I'm sharing this in case someone stumbles upon the same issue.

Right now I'm using [node-tdd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=prashaantt.node-tdd), which was a bit difficult to set up since its Windows support is limited, but it seems to fit the bill just fine.